# Python: errno13: Permission denied when trying to copy folders

Tags: python, errno

Been through the numerous other '`errno13`' posts, but found nothing that helps here.

The file directory is as follows:

```
C:\\Users\\My HP\\Desktop\\Python\\Automate_the_boring_stuff\\Misc\\Eating\\Pie\\carrot.txt
```

And here's my code for copying folders:

```
for folderTitle, childFolders, fileNames in os.walk('C:\\Users\\My HP\\Desktop\\Python\\Automate_the_boring_stuff\\Misc\\Eating'):

     for folder in childFolders:
         shutil.copy(folder, folder + '_backup')
```

Running this causes the '`errno13: Permission denied`' error. 
Are the folders somehow in 'in use' or otherwise not copyable? They are not open in Windows as far as I can tell. Task manager shows Windows Explorer to be inactive.

This issue exists on every editor I've tried (Geany, IDLE and jupyter are the ones I have access to).

(As an aside, opening the Python script in IDLE causes an error if you try to import shell utility; the error states that shutil can't be found. Not had this issue with Geany/Jupyter).

Can anyone help?

Comment: are you sure that you have the needed permission on the folder? A permission error means that the user which own the proccess can access in that way to the resource

Comment: @Mondo-Cane thanks for the response. I'm performing this action on my personal machine, not a corporate/organisational one. And the folder doesn't appear to have any permission restrictions. I can manually copy the folders fine.

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions to create new files in the target directory?

Comment: try a shorter path, copy it to C:\\Users\\My HP\\Desktop\\Python, and see if it works,

Comment: @jordanm I can manually copy folders into this folder OK, so I presume I have copy permissions.

Comment: @trigonom Thanks. For some reason, both the shorter filepath and the original filepath are now producing 'errno2: No such file or directory' when they reach the first file contained in the parent folder. The weird thing is that the error correctly states the name of the first file/folder present in the directory, even though it states that it doesn't exist! Eg: Errno2: No such file or directory: 'Food'. Then how was it able to correctly identify the file as 'Food'? Is it expecting a full directory (filepath + filename)?

Comment: again it seems like windows path limit, the destination folder exists?

Comment: @trigonom Apologies-not sure I understand. Do you mean a character limit? The issue seems to affect files/files of any path length as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
path = r"D:\test"
file_path = r"D:\tmp.txt"
while(True):
    print(len(path))
    os.mkdir(path)
    new_file_path = os.path.join(path,file_path)
    os.rename(file_path,new_file_path)
    file_path = new_file_path
    path = os.path.join(path,"test")
```

the above make a longer path with inner folders, end with [WinError 206] The filename or extension is too long, at length 252

```
while(True):
    print(len(file_path))
    new_file_path = file_path+".txt"
    os.rename(file_path,new_file_path)
    file_path = new_file_path
```

the above causes [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: at length 256
using shutil.move instead of os.rename causes [Errno 2] No such file or directory
not sure that this is the problem, but try using less folder in folder

Comment: Thanks, will give that a try.